# Rename odbc.ini file

Tags: filenames, rename, putty

Can you please let me know how can I replace the name from `odbc.ini` (old name) to `.odbc.ini` (new name) in putty using Linux commands?

Answer (score 1):

Replacing odbc.ini to .odbc.ini would make the file "hidden". It will still be there though. You can use mv

```
mv odbc.ini .odbc.ini
```